# Is "that of" used here correctly?

Tags: grammar, that, scientific-language

I wonder if "that of" used in the following question doesn't create grammatical error. If it does, then I also wonder the corrected form or alternatives.

The statement:

> The running time devided by a factor reflects the performance of the CPU used here compared to that of used in the previous research.

Comment: It should be just *that*, not *that of*. Must be a typo.

Comment: Very poorly phrased.

Comment: If it said ... performance of the CPU used here compared to that of the CPU used in the previous research... that would be grammatical, but it is very clumsy either way.

Comment: What's the source of this quote?

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is ungrammatical, uses the word factor incorrectly and mispells the word "divided." It should read:

> The running time is divided by a constant to make the performance of
> the CPU comparable to that of the CPU used in the previous research.